# Sorting a dataframe with multiple colums using Python and Polars

Tags: python, dataframe, sorting, python-polars

I have a data sorting problem where the original data consists of three 'blocks' containing a 'parent' row and two 'children' rows. A minimum working example looks like this:

```
import polars as pl
df_original = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        'Direction': ["Buy", "Sell", "Buy", "Sell", "Sell", "Buy"],
        'Order ID': [None, '123_1', '123_0', None, '456_1', '456_0'],
        'Parent Order ID': [123, None, None, 456, None, None],

    }
)
```

I would like to order these based on the parent row. If the parent is a 'Buy' then the next row should be the 'Sell' child-order, the third row should be the 'Buy' order.

For a parent 'Sell' order it needs to be followed buy the 'Buy' order and then the 'Sell' order.

I have tried it with polars.sort(), but I am missing a piece of logic and can't find out what it is.

The final result should look like this:

```
df_sorted = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        'Direction': ["Buy", "Sell", "Buy", "Sell", "Buy", "Sell"],
        'Order ID': [None, '123_1', '123_0', None, '456_0', '456_1'],
        'Parent Order ID': [123, None, None, 456, None, None],

    }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly you want to alternate the order of `"Buy"`/`"Sell"`.

This snippet produces your desired output.

```py
df = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        'Direction': ["Buy", "Sell", "Buy", "Sell", "Sell", "Buy"],
        'Order ID': [None, '123_1', '123_0', None, '456_1', '456_0'],
        'Parent Order ID': [123, None, None, 456, None, None],

    }
)

consecutive = (pl.col("Direction") != pl.col("Direction").shift())
df.filter(consecutive).vstack(df.filter(~consecutive))
```

```
shape: (6, 3)
┌───────────┬──────────┬─────────────────┐
│ Direction ┆ Order ID ┆ Parent Order ID │
│ ---       ┆ ---      ┆ ---             │
│ str       ┆ str      ┆ i64             │
╞═══════════╪══════════╪═════════════════╡
│ Buy       ┆ null     ┆ 123             │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ Sell      ┆ 123_1    ┆ null            │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ Buy       ┆ 123_0    ┆ null            │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ Sell      ┆ null     ┆ 456             │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ Buy       ┆ 456_0    ┆ null            │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ Sell      ┆ 456_1    ┆ null            │
└───────────┴──────────┴─────────────────┘
```